# A lot of errors after Android 2.3 Launcher Source Code is imported into my workspace

Tags: android, launcher, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have task to modify android gingerbread launcher (2.3). I want to download launcher's sources and add some functionality. I have found sources here:

[android Gingerbread launcher sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git/+/gingerbread)

I download this and import into workspace as is. As a result I get numerous compile errors (some classes are missing, instance variables are missing, etc). Why? I mean why wouldn't it compile? What should I do to make it compile?

P.S. By the way, when project is imported, used platform as per project settings is not 2.3, so I have to manually set it to 2.3. However, numerous errors still remain.

Answer (score 4):

To convert an AOSP application into a standalone SDK application, you will need to find all the "classes and variable not present in the SDK" and remove/replace the references to them. The simplest is to remove the references to them, if the app will still run with reduced functionality. For references to internal resources, you can simply copy those to your project and modify the R values to point to your local copy. You are welcome to examine the "classes and variable not present in the SDK" and determine that you can copy those as well (refactoring them into a new package), in which case you would update your project to refer to the copied and refactored classes.

Comment: Where can I find so called "classes and variable not present in the SDK"? I tried to google it, but no result.

Comment: this might help, please check it out http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

Answer (score 2):

The easier solution would be to use someone's source where they already did that..Here found one at

[Launcher2 full compilable Ginngerbread lancher code](https://github.com/goodev/GingerbreadLauncher2)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/CompilingLauncher2).

It is the Launcher2 from ICS, not GB, but they are very similar.
**From Wiki:** Note that it is not completely bug free, and adding widgets will crash the app (as it uses a system level permission. Maybe if you installed via root it'll work).

Here's a list of what all I had to do, that I can recall doing:

There are lots of methods like `setFastXXX` (for example, `setFastAlpha()`) that aren't available to us. Changing these to `setXXX` (for example, 'setAlpha()`) worked for me.

Some thing which are available to us via `getSystemService()` are initialized directly in the code, like the usage of the Vibrator class. These need to be changed to use `getSystemService()`.